# What is the best video editor on Ubuntu for editing multi-format/multi-eco?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, video-editor

I have many video clips with different formats and I want to create a short movies by joining them. Most of the clips are taken with Nokia N8 and Lumia 800. I am using Ubuntu, I have tried many of editors but I can not edit/video clips due to different video formats. Which open source editor should I use to achieve following tasks:

- Join different vidoe formats/encoding to produce on single movie
- Export to different formats (.avi, youtube, etc)
- Add texts on the clips and insert images

I don't want to install and try many of them.

Comment: try openshot video editor. install like so `sudo apt-get install openshot` to see what it can do check out this http://www.openshot.org/features

Comment: Did you already try kdenlive?

Comment: [List of video editing software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software)

Answer (score 6):

You could try [OpenShot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/), which has also got some 3D [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) animations for titles, but it can be a bit frustrating.  Other user-friendly options are [PiTiVI](http://www.pitivi.org/) and [Kdenlive](http://kdenlive.org/).  As far as I've used them, you can easily join clips, insert text and images and export videos to different formats.  There is a list of open-source editing software on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software#Open-source).

Within a few months [Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/), a very professional editor, should be available for Ubuntu.

edit: Lightworks is now available for Ubuntu

Comment: Where is lightworks available? Or are you talking about the beta version - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/11/lightworks-for-linux-beta-updated

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [OpenShot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/). This blog post talks about it a little. It is able to use various video file types to create a small movie.

http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/the-best-video-editor-for-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: Oh.. No. I would not suggest this app.